# ZREM on Redis Sorted Set

Tags: redis, sortedset, redis-py

What will happen if 2 workers call ZREM on the same element of a sorted set at the same time? Will it return true to the worker which actually removes the element and false to the other to indicate it doesn't exist or will it return true to both? In other words is ZREM atomic internally?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Redis is (mostly) single-threaded so all its operations are atomic and ZREM is no exception. Your question, however, is actually about doing a "ZPOP" atomically so there are two possible ways to do that.

**Option 1: WATCH/MULTI/EXEC**

In pseudo code, this is how an optimistic transaction would look:

```
:start
WATCH somekey
member = ZREVRANGE somekey 0 0
MULTI
ZREM somekey member
if not EXEC goto :start // or quit trying
```

**Option 2: Lua script**

```
zpop.lua:

local member = redis.call('ZREVRANGE', KEYS[1], 0, 0)
return redis.call('ZREM', KEYS[1], member)

redis-cli --eval zpop.lua somekey
```

**Note - The Importance of Atomicity**
In case you decide not to use these mechanisms that ensure atomicity, you'll be running into issues sooner than you think. Here's a possible scenario:

```
Process A                Redis Server            Process B
ZREVRANGE ------------>
          <------------- foo
                                      <--------- ZADD +inf bar
                                   OK --------->
ZREM foo -------------->
         <-------------- 1
```

In the above example, after A fetches foo, B inserts bar with an absurdly high score so it becomes the top element in the set. A, however, will continue and remove the previously-at-the-top foo.

Comment: This means its OK to get the top most element, remove it, and then check if it succeeded or not? This will be done just to make sure every worker gets a different element.

Comment: If ZREM's reply is 1 (assuming that you're trying to remove a single member), that means it was removed. No need to check nor worry about another worker getting the same element - it won't be there anymore.

Comment: Yes but before removing I need to know which element to remove. This will be done by making a range query to get the element with highest score. The problem is if 2 workers get the same element one should only be able to remove it so other knows I need to re-fetch another element. Basically, I am trying to implement ZPOP which doesn't exist.

Comment: In that case you'll want some atomicity baked into your flow - a Lua script can solve this (by doing both ZRANGE and ZREM one after the other), or you could use a WATCH/MULTI/EXEC "block" for an optimistic variant of with the same end result (i.e. atomicity)

Comment: Thanks for the example. What if I handle this programmatically by getting first member, removing it, and then checking the response. If ZREM returns 1 proceed otherwise try to get another member. I will only have 2 or 3 workers so not a lot of concurrency but I still need to handle it.